# Is it safe to store Azure b2c details in code or do I need to obfuscate?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I've written a Xamarin Forms app (Android and iOS) that uses Azure b2c for its security. The user has to log in to b2c before they can do anything in the app. In order to facilitate the login, I'm using MSAL which requires an App ID/Client ID guid and a tenant url, both of which I store in code. Is this a safe thing to do, or would people advise I obfuscate my code? There's nothing particularly sensitive in there apart from the b2c stuff.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client ID and tenant URL are not something that is secret.
A user could just get those from the URL to which they navigate to log in.

So there is no need to obfuscate these.
Client secrets are of course things that you should never have in a mobile app.